# ajax load inner html into div from drop down menu select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Drop Down menu that I want to use as a navigational menu. The drop down is coded with js and css to give it the style look and feel that I want. Values are set to numbers to show the links in order and the class is used to load an image beside the Text inside of the drop down menu. What I am using is this code to load links inside this certain div (apDiv2) 
**AJAX LOADER**

```
$('.menu_nav').click(function() {
var href = $(this).attr('href');

// loading gif//
$('#apDiv2').empty().append($('<img src="/loader.gif" />'));

$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: href,
    success: function(content)
    {
        $('#apDiv2').html (content);
    }
});

return false;
});
```

I want to be able to use this Ajax Code to load innerHTML pages of my website into the Div 2. I also Use a modenizer.js for functioning of this drop down menu. Is there any way I can Get this menu to load a page into this appointed div without rearranging my style and look of this dropdown menu?

Here is the Menu's js? 
 **DropDown Menu Js**

```
;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

'use strict';

$.DropDown = function( options, element ) {
    this.$el = $( element );
    this._init( options );
};

// the options
$.DropDown.defaults = {
    speed : 300,
    easing : 'ease',
    gutter : 0,
    // initial stack effect
    stack : true,
    // delay between each option animation
    delay : 0,
    // random angle and positions for the options
    random : false,
    // rotated [right||left||false] : the options will be rotated to thr right side or left side.
    // make sure to tune the transform origin in the stylesheet
    rotated : false,
    // effect to slide in the options. value is the margin to start with
    slidingIn : false,
    onOptionSelect : function(opt) { return false; }
};

$.DropDown.prototype = {

    _init : function( options ) {

        // options
        this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.DropDown.defaults, options );
        this._layout();
        this._initEvents();

    },
    _layout : function() {

        var self = this;
        this.minZIndex = 1000;
        var value = this._transformSelect();
        this.opts = this.listopts.children( 'li' );
        this.optsCount = this.opts.length;
        this.size = { width : this.dd.width(), height : this.dd.height() };

        var elName = this.$el.attr( 'name' ), elId = this.$el.attr( 'id' ),
            inputName = elName !== undefined ? elName : elId !== undefined ? elId : 'cd-dropdown-' + ( new Date() ).getTime();

        this.inputEl = $( '<input type="hidden" name="' + inputName + '" value="' + value + '"></input>' ).insertAfter( this.selectlabel );

        this.selectlabel.css( 'z-index', this.minZIndex + this.optsCount );
        this._positionOpts();
        if( Modernizr.csstransitions ) {
            setTimeout( function() { self.opts.css( 'transition', 'all ' + self.options.speed + 'ms ' + self.options.easing ); }, 25 );
        }

    },
    _transformSelect : function() {

        var optshtml = '', selectlabel = '', value = -1;
        this.$el.children( 'option' ).each( function() {

            var $this = $( this ),
                val = isNaN( $this.attr( 'value' ) ) ? $this.attr( 'value' ) : Number( $this.attr( 'value' ) ) ,
                classes = $this.attr( 'class' ),
                selected = $this.attr( 'selected' ),
                label = $this.text();

            if( val !== -1 ) {
                optshtml += 
                    classes !== undefined ? 
                        '<li data-value="' + val + '"><span class="' + classes + '">' + label + '</span></li>' :
                        '<li data-value="' + val + '"><span>' + label + '</span></li>';
            }

            if( selected ) {
                selectlabel = label;
                value = val;
            }

        } );

        this.listopts = $( '<ul/>' ).append( optshtml );
        this.selectlabel = $( '<span/>' ).append( selectlabel );
        this.dd = $( '<div class="cd-dropdown"/>' ).append( this.selectlabel, this.listopts ).insertAfter( this.$el );
        this.$el.remove();

        return value;

    },
    _positionOpts : function( anim ) {

        var self = this;

        this.listopts.css( 'height', 'auto' );
        this.opts
            .each( function( i ) {
                $( this ).css( {
                    zIndex : self.minZIndex + self.optsCount - 1 - i,
                    top : self.options.slidingIn ? ( i + 1 ) * ( self.size.height + self.options.gutter ) : 0,
                    left : 0,
                    marginLeft : self.options.slidingIn ? i % 2 === 0 ? self.options.slidingIn : - self.options.slidingIn : 0,
                    opacity : self.options.slidingIn ? 0 : 1,
                    transform : 'none'
                } );
            } );

        if( !this.options.slidingIn ) {
            this.opts
                .eq( this.optsCount - 1 )
                .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 9 : 0, left : this.options.stack ? 4 : 0, width : this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 8 : this.size.width, transform : 'none' } )
                .end()
                .eq( this.optsCount - 2 )
                .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 6 : 0, left : this.options.stack ? 2 : 0, width : this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 4 : this.size.width, transform : 'none' } )
                .end()
                .eq( this.optsCount - 3 )
                .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 3 : 0, left : 0, transform : 'none' } );
        }

    },
    _initEvents : function() {

        var self = this;

        this.selectlabel.on( 'mousedown.dropdown', function( event ) {
            self.opened ? self.close() : self.open();
            return false;

        } );

        this.opts.on( 'click.dropdown', function() {
            if( self.opened ) {
                var opt = $( this );
                self.options.onOptionSelect( opt );
                self.inputEl.val( opt.data( 'value' ) );
                self.selectlabel.html( opt.html() );
                self.close();
            }
        } );

    },
    open : function() {
        var self = this;
        this.dd.toggleClass( 'cd-active' );
        this.listopts.css( 'height', ( this.optsCount + 1 ) * ( this.size.height + this.options.gutter ) );
        this.opts.each( function( i ) {

            $( this ).css( {
                opacity : 1,
                top : self.options.rotated ? self.size.height + self.options.gutter : ( i + 1 ) * ( self.size.height + self.options.gutter ),
                left : self.options.random ? Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 - 5 ) : 0,
                width : self.size.width,
                marginLeft : 0,
                transform : self.options.random ?
                    'rotate(' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 - 5 ) + 'deg)' :
                    self.options.rotated ?
                        self.options.rotated === 'right' ?
                            'rotate(-' + ( i * 5 ) + 'deg)' :
                            'rotate(' + ( i * 5 ) + 'deg)'
                        : 'none',
                transitionDelay : self.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ? self.options.slidingIn ? ( i * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : ( ( self.optsCount - 1 - i ) * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : 0
            } );

        } );
        this.opened = true;

    },
    close : function() {

        var self = this;
        this.dd.toggleClass( 'cd-active' );
        if( this.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ) {
            this.opts.each( function( i ) {
                $( this ).css( { 'transition-delay' : self.options.slidingIn ? ( ( self.optsCount - 1 - i ) * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : ( i * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' } );
            } );
        }
        this._positionOpts( true );
        this.opened = false;

    }

}

$.fn.dropdown = function( options ) {
    var instance = $.data( this, 'dropdown' );
    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
        this.each(function() {
            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
        });
    }
    else {
        this.each(function() {
            instance ? instance._init() : instance = $.data( this,       'dropdown', new $.DropDown( options, this ) );
        });
    }
    return instance;
};

} )( jQuery, window );
```

Is there Any Way that I can Impliment the Ajax Loader coding Into The DropDown Menu JS? Please help I am a begginner to this Ajax and JS

Comment: you want to do that inside JS file itself ?? What issues you are facing than ?

Comment: yes I want to impliment the ajax code into the drop down menu JS so that when selected It will open the selected link from the menu in the DIV I have appointed....Will It Help for me to upload it to my website and give you the link? @MonkeyPatch

Comment: What you have so far seems like the right strategy. Is something in particular not working right now? Is the click event not firing? Is the ajax call not being made?

Comment: No @mattfetz it is giving me no function.... when i use the drop down menu and select it.... Nothing loads... mean while i placed buttons at the top (which I dont want to use) and they load the content just fine. but not when using the drop menu

Comment: When you click the drop down is it hitting your server?

Comment: @mattfetz please take a look www.foreverthaempire.com

Answer (score 0):

In your Dropdown js code you have a event listener called `close`. In here you can grab the selected element by calling `this.inputEl.val()`. This will give you a id number thats assigned to that particular nav item you clicked. With that number create the url that would correspond with the Id and make a ajax call to that url. Get the contents from the url and append them where you want to.

Maybe something like this

```
if(this.inputEl.val() == 1){
    herf = "test.com/home"
}else if(this.inputEl.val() == 2){
    href = "test.com/music"
}//etc

$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: herf,
    success: function(content)
    {
        $('#apDiv2').html(content);
    }
});
```

So you are going to have to put code like this into that close function in the dropdown js essentially.

Comment: Right now your talking foreign to me...... I have classes assigned already for the listed items they put icons/logos beside the drop menu labels is there any way around this?

Comment: i already have a class assigned can I get it to do the same thing if I use an ID? If so could you show me how? post a sample code or something

Comment: Ok I updated the answer to be a bit easier. I can help you so much with the actual ajax code because I don't know what your back end code is. but what I provided should be pretty close anyway.

Comment: I dont have any back end code...the site is all front end java html5 and css  and this didnt seem to work for me....